# Is $f:X\to X$, $f(x,y)=(2x,3y)$ continuous with $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and the topology $\mathcal{T}=\{\text{Open disks centered at the origin}\}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Is $f:X\to X$, $f(x,y)=(2x,3y)$ continuous with $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ and the topology $\mathcal{T}=\{\text{Open disks centered at the origin}\}\cup\{\emptyset\}\cup\{X\}$

So I want to prove this by showing the preimage of any open set is open.

Let $U\in \mathcal{T}$

then if $(x,y)\in f^{-1}(U)$

then $f(x,y)=(2x,3y)\in U$

then there exists an $\epsilon >0$ such that $B_{\epsilon}((2x,3y))\subseteq U$

Not sure how to continue from here. I want to show that there is a ball $B_r((x,y))$ such that if $(p,q)\in B_r((x,y))$ then $(p,q)\in B_\epsilon(f(x,y))$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Take any open disk in $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and compute its preimage under $f$. Is it again a disk?

Comment: Is it an elipse? Cause the $y$ values get divided by $3$ and the $x$ values only by $2$? Is it not continuous then?

Comment: @AColoredReptile Correct.

Comment: So I should show that $f^{-1}(D_r(0))=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}: (\frac{x}{2})^2+(\frac{y}{3})^2<r^2\}$ and then prove that this set can't be a union of open disks?

Comment: Well, the only open sets in your topology are disks around $0$. That this set is not such a disk is pretty obvious I would say.